# Cordova API device don't work in windows phone 8 device

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

with this code

```
<body onload="LoadDeviceInfo()">
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p id="deviceInfo">Device Info</p>
        <script>

            function LoadDeviceInfo()
            {
            var element = document.getElementById("deviceInfo");
            element.innerHTML =
                "Device Name : " + device.name + "<br />"
                + "Cordova Version : " + device.cordova + "<br />"
                + "Device Platform : " + device.platform + "<br />"
                + "Device UUID : " + device.uuid + "<br />"
                + "OS Version : " + device.version + "<br />"
                + "Device Model : " + device.model + "<br />";
            }
        </script>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result when i build on android device (Asus Zenfone4)
[image]

And result when i build on windows phone 8 (Nokia lumia620)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

*device.name* has been deprecated since PhoneGap 2.3.0. If you're using the latest version of PhoneGap (3.5.0 at the time of writing), please use *device.model* instead.